# stopPropagation() not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Having some issues in IE. Things are fin in Chrom/Opera etc. But in IE I go to click and toggleClass but nothing happens. I thought implementing cancel.bubble would help me but that is not the case.

Following is the HTML:

```
<div class="title">
  <h2>Catamarans</h2>
  <div class="dateSelect">
    <div class="prev">
      <p>Prev</p>
      <a href="#" onClick="dateChange('formattedDate')">< month</a> </div>
    <div class="next">
      <p>Next</p>
      <a href="#" onClick="dateChange('formattedDate')">month ></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in the JQuery

```
function dateChange(dateInput){
    //creating new instance of the date based on the date passed into the function  
    var nextDay = new Date(dateInput); 


//the date will change according to the date passed in from 1 day to 1 month
nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate()+1);

//The following will go into another function which formats the date in such a way that vbscript can handle it.
nextDay = dateFormat(nextDay);

//updating the values for the a tag in the onclick attribute. and appending to the strVar variable
var strVar="";
strVar += "             <div class=\"prev\">";
strVar += "                    <p>Prev<\/p>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevMonth+"')\">< month<\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevWeek+"')\">< week<\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+prevDay+"')\">< day<\/a>";
strVar += "                <\/div>";
strVar += "                ";
strVar += "                <div class=\"next\">";
strVar += "                 <p>Next<\/p>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextMonth+"')\">month ><\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextWeek+"')\">week ><\/a>";
strVar += "                    <a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onClick=\"dateChange('"+nextDay+"')\">day ><\/a>";
strVar += "                <\/div>";


//For each .title it finds, it will look for its child .dateselect and remove .dateselect child. It will then append new data to .dateselect with the updated values
$(".title").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).find('.dateSelect').children().remove();
    $(this).find('.dateSelect').append(strVar);

    var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
      if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
          if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingCatamaran&date="+dateInput+"");
              //alert(dateInput);
          }
          else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date="+dateInput+"");
          }
          else{
              $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=nothing&date="+dateInput+"");
          }
      }
});
//Stops propagation so when day,week or month are clicked, the table won't disappear 
event.stopPropagation();

}

$(document).ready(function() {

/*$("table").first().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date="+current+"", function(response, status, xhr){
    if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $("table").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
});*/

$(".title").click(function(event){


  $(this).next().toggleClass("hide");
  var boatName = $(this).next().attr('id');
  if(!$(this).next().hasClass('hide')){
      if(boatName == "SailingCatamaran"){

          $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingCatamaran&date=");
      }
      else if(boatName == "PowerCatamaran"){

          $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=PowerCatamaran&date=");
      }
      else{

          $(this).next().load("availability.asp?boatType=SailingMonohull&date=");
      }
  }
  $(this).children().last().toggleClass("hide");
  $(this).find('.dateSelect').toggleClass("hide");
  //alert("title being clicked");
});

event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I have stripped out unneccessary/duplicate code so it's a little easier to read. To explain my code in words, I have a div with a class of title, you click it to show/hide its sibling table. when table is shown you will see some A tags and when clicked it will call dateChange() load up the appropriate infomation. the clicking to show hide the table and clicking the A tag doesn't work in IE. I suspect other browsers too. Any ideas? I'm not sure if dateChange() needs an event or something? Still new to this haha! Cheers in advance!

Comment: your `event.stopPropagation();` calls seem completely out of context... there is no `event` in the places you're calling it

Comment: @compid are you referring to the one in dateChange() method or the one in the document.ready?

Comment: okay, the formatting confused me

Comment: try event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your issue is caused by a difference in the handling of the `event` object in IE. In IE9 and before, the event object is not a local variable in the event handler's context, but instead a global variable.

Instead of directly calling `event.stopPropagation()`, try to do this first:

```
event = event || window.event;
event.stopPropagation();
```

IE9 apparently populates the `window.event` object instead of the local variable.

---

A much better way would be to use jQuery to bind events to buttons, and never to use the `onclick` attribute in HTML. As pointed out in the comments, jQuery will normalize the event object so that it can be accessed from a common interface. An example of this would be:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="prevMonthBtn">&lt; month</a>
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
$("#prevMonthBtn").click(dateChange);
```

You can find an alternative way to pass the arguments `formattedDate` in.

Comment: May I clarify, do I put this code in place of where I have my current event.stopPropagation() at the moment? Or else where?

Comment: jQuery normalizes events, this isn't useful with jQuery.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: yes, but when Akira put `onClick="dateChange('formattedDate')"` in the HTML, jQuery isn't involved.

Comment: @AkiraDawson try placing it in your dateChange method. I've updated my answer to cover attaching events using javascript

Comment: @compid I have changed my code a bit now. You click and it works once, and once only now. Still no go in IE either.

when page is loaded I have this: 
<a href="#" name="05,26,2013" id="prevMonth">&lt; month</a>

and in jQuery I now have:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".title").click(function(event){
        //code stuff
        //no stoppropagation
    });
$("#prevMonth").click(function(event){
  var dateParam = $(this).attr('name');
  dateChange(dateParam);
  event = event || window.event;
event.stopPropagation();
 });
 
 event.stopProp;
}); 

Am I getting on the right track at least?

Comment: Sorry about lack of formatting.. Still getting used to posting stuff on here, not just reading answers lol

Comment: awesome..thanks for this...i was scratching my head.... I dispise debugging for IE 9

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that *event* is not within the scope of dateChange. This works in some browsers because they make it available to the function that is calling *dateChange* but IE does not do that.

The root of the problem is that you're not appending your links "correctly". It'd be best to not generate html like you're doing with your *setVar* there, and generate DOM elements with jQuery instead, which would look something like this:

```
var $prev_container = $( '<div>' )
  .addClass( 'prev' )
  .appendTo( $(this).find('.dateSelect') );

var $prev_month_link = $( '<a>' )
  .html( "month" )
  .click(function(event){
    dateChange( prevMonth ) // I'm not sure where prevMonth comes from, but I would pass it in to dateChange explicitly
    event.stopPropagation();
  })
  .appendTo( $prev_container )

  // and so on for the other links
```

The reason for this is that you have full control of the scope of your event handling functions while at the same time decoupling your markup from your javascript.

I think in most cases where you find yourself using onClick and writing markup from js you have to stop and think about it because there is almost always a way to do it by interacting with the DOM directly.

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'll give this a shot and get back to you! I realise my code is sloppy. I can never predict how big these projects explode!

Comment: I gave it a shot, it works! sort of! But it's progress!
I implemented you code on line 56 at the following:
http://pastebin.com/jhppDZ43

after 1 or so clicks the dates in the name attribute become aN,aN or some shizz. @thatjuan

Comment: @AkiraDawson NaN means "not a number". It could be that at some point your prevMonth is something other than a number. You can use console.log( prevMonth ); to try and trace what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

//event.stopPropagation(); --> Comment this line

//Add below line

(event.stopPropagation) ? event.stopPropagation() : event.cancelBubble = true;